# Saving batches' data in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

I need to accumulate data from batches for some time for latter processing. I am using Spark 1.6.3.

I need to accumulate them in form `(tag, [[time, value],..]`).
So far i have tried `updateStateByKey`:

```
time = [0]
def updateFunc(new_values, last_sum,time):
    time[0] += 5
    if time == 10:
        time = 0
        return None
    return (last_sum or []) + new_values

data = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                  .map(lambda word: (word, ['t','t1'])) \
                  .updateStateByKey(lambda x,y :updateFunc(x,y,time))
data.pprint()
```

The data is being added. But, attempt to flush data after 10 seconds doesnt work. (I am doing it wrong way)

Also i have tried to use `window`:

```
data= lines.flatMap(lambda lime: line.split(' ')\
    .map(lambda tag: (tag: ['time', 'value']))\
    .window(10, 2)\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y : y + x)`
```

But, this yields a one-dimensional long list. Which is not useful.
 Any leads? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = lines.flatMap(lambda x: list(x)).map(lambda x: (x, [('time', 'value')]))
counts = items.reduceByKeyAndWindow(lambda x, y: x + y, invFunc=None, windowDuration=3, slideDuration=2)
```

Try this